# Constraints keep going haywire every time I reopen an XCode project

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Every time I close and reopen XCode 6 beta 6, my previously-happy constraints are messed up and I have to click on the yellow dot to get to the "Misplaced Views" thingy, then click on each yellow triangle, choose Update Frame, and click Fix Misplacement to correct the problem. Is this a bug in the beta or have I done something wrong, perhaps? Constraints in XCode (to me, at least) are horrible things to tame at the best of times, so maybe it's not a bug?

Once fixed, and XCode neither complains about nor renders the widgets badly, it's fine. But as soon as I close then reopen the project, they're messed up again.

Comment: How about Xcode 6 GM seed?

Comment: There is such a thing, eh? Well, then I'd best go fetch it :-) Thanks.

Comment: XCode 6 GM doesn't support OS X targets for 10.9, and choosing 10.10 doesn't help (I'm guessing it mustn't include 10.10). That's a bit of a downer.

Comment: So you're saying you cannot target 10.9 using Xcode 6?

Comment: [It would seem not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777921/compile-swift-on-10-9), not unless you download 6.1 beta and steal from it or use it instead of 6.0

Comment: I'm currently using 6.1.1 and my text boxes, labels, etc, are all suddenly so far off the screen they can't be seen. Why on earth do constraints keep going bezerk???? Is this beyond Apple or something? This is just ridiculous!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same thing on a project I'm working on. What I've observed is a circular connection among the views in the storyboard in question, so that it's possible to segue around and around a particular path or paths. The views are all embedded in a TabBarController, and each tab has its own NavigationController.

So for instance:

- Activity View (programmatically selected tab), segue to ...
- Detail View, segue to ...
- Profile View (programmatically selected tab), segue to ...
- Item View, segue to ...
- Detail view

... and so on

This seems to introduce random screwups to the views.

What I have **not yet** done is test this by removing the circular segue paths. I'm not sure I ever will, since the circular segue paths are part of the functionality of the app. But I'm pretty sure that was about where this weird behavior got introduced. I'll be interested to hear whether the same is true of your project.

Comment: I'm writing an OSX app and so far it seems as if it might happen when I copy and paste text fields, etc, from my window to a custom view (thereby creating duplicates or something?). I tried cutting and pasting but it still resulted in the same problem. I'm moving a heap of things out of said window into separate custom views which will be placed in an NSStackView, so perhaps that will limit any damage that might happen in future. I'd much rather be doing this app in .NET - I would have finished it months ago :-(